# ios app crashes without error (even with calling empty action via button click)

Tags: ios, error-handling, crash

i found similar issues but none of them resolved my problem.

There are some viewcontrollers and working application.

I added one button to one of the viewcontrollers and binded a "sampleclick" action. there is nothing (no codes, no lines, just an empty method) in this action and application crashes with following blocks :

All output log :

```
(lldb)
```

and stack :

```
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:
0x10ed08c:  movl   8(%esp), %ecx
0x10ed090:  movl   4(%esp), %eax
0x10ed094:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x10ed096:  je     0x10ed0e8                 ; objc_msgSend + 92
0x10ed098:  movl   (%eax), %edx
0x10ed09a:  pushl  %edi
0x10ed09b:  movl   8(%edx), %edi
0x10ed09e:  pushl  %esi
***0x10ed09f:  movl   (%edi), %esi   >>> crashes here with :Thread1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS*** (code=1,address: .....)
0x10ed0a1:  movl   %ecx, %edx
0x10ed0a3:  shrl   $2, %edx
0x10ed0a6:  andl   %esi, %edx
0x10ed0a8:  movl   8(%edi,%edx,4), %eax
0x10ed0ac:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x10ed0ae:  je     0x10ed0b9                 ; objc_msgSend + 45
0x10ed0b0:  cmpl   (%eax), %ecx
0x10ed0b2:  je     0x10ed0d0                 ; objc_msgSend + 68
0x10ed0b4:  addl   $1, %edx
0x10ed0b7:  jmp    0x10ed0a6                 ; objc_msgSend + 26
0x10ed0b9:  popl   %esi
0x10ed0ba:  popl   %edi
0x10ed0bb:  movl   4(%esp), %edx
0x10ed0bf:  movl   (%edx), %eax
0x10ed0c1:  jmp    0x10ed0d9                 ; objc_msgSend + 77
0x10ed0c3:  nopw   %cs:(%eax,%eax)
```

Comment: nothing can be said untless you Post your ViewController's code where you added your button..

Comment: `objc_msgSend` is your problem. You code is trying to access an object that doesn't exist any more or trying to send a selector to an object, which doesn't understand the selector.

Comment: Try entering `x/s $r1` on the debugger when the crash occurs. What does it tell you?

Comment: just make sure the ViewController in which your button added, have a parent viewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it!!!!

I resolved it by removing whole application step by step for each action and property and found the culprit :
(maybe helps somebody having the same issue)

detailsviewcontroller is a typical uiviewcontroller and was opened by following code :

```
    detailviewcontroller *vc = [[detailviewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"detailviewcontroller" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:vc.view];
```

i replaced by the following code (just deleted the detailviewcontroller word and *) and the problem is resolved :

```
    vc = [[detailviewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"detailviewcontroller" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:vc.view];
```

this also shows i should study objective c a bit more for declarations ;)

Comment: Your answer works, seems its bcoz of ARC and scope of the object due to the local declaration.

Answer (score 5):

One possible answer to your issue is that you are trying to send a message to a deallocated instance of an object.

Try looking for zoombies (press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, select the *Diagnostics* tab and activate *Enable Zombie Objects*). Every released object will become an instance of NSZombie, which will log messages to the console if you ever try to access them instead of crashing.

Also, on ARM architecture (which concerns iOS), `r0` should point towards the receiver of the message. You can try investigating this. It may yield useful informations. (use `p/x $r0` command on the debugger. If you execute `x/s $r1`, you should get the selector name.)

**Note:**

If you are to debug crashes that occurs within `objc_msgSend()` then, I strongly recommend you to take a look at [[objc explain]: So you crashed in objc_msgSend()](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2008/09/22/objc_explain_So_you_crashed_in_objc_msgSend.html) on the Hamster Emporium archive. It contains valuable tips & tricks to get most informations out of the debugger as well as investigate why the crash occurred.

**Edit:** From the comments, but without the code, one can only guess that *somewhere in your code* an object (likely `detailviewcontroller`) registered for events but has been deallocated too soon. Hence the crash when sending the action. This is only a hint, but IMHO it is worth investigating in the debugger.

Comment: hi Jean,it very interesting because i deleted whole code in this viewcontroller and left just one action and this action does not have any code inside.No variables, no properties,no any code. button click action still crashes with the same error. I just enabled nszoombies and got following error in log pane : 2013-04-21 15:28:59.094 myiphoneproject[29061:c07] *** -[detailviewcontroller performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7159360 (edit:here is the call stack 0x1c8ca91:  calll
0x1c8ca96: int3   
0x1c8ca97: calll 0x1d70a00; symbol stub for:getpid

Comment: This means that you are trying to send a message to a dealocated instance, as suspected. This is what causes the crash. Try to figure out why the object is deallocated in the first place. You probably either: *need to retain it* OR *need to zero the pointer out* depending on your model. To be certain, try entering `x/s $r1` on the debugger when the crash occurs. What does it tell you? Also, compare the output of `p/x $r0` with the `xxx` value in message sent to deallocated instance `xxx`. Any further investigation would require the code.

Comment: i understand but there is nothing on my viewcontroller. i removed everything and just one button and one empty action (does nothing). how can it crash while just calling the empty action??

Comment: It can crash because it doesn't *just* send an empty action. Without the code, I can only guess that *somewhere in your code* an object (likely `detailviewcontroller`) registered for events but has been deallocated too soon. Hence the crash when sending the action.

Answer (score 0):

here is the .m file :

```
#import "detailviewcontroller.h"

@interface detailviewcontroller ()

@end

@implementation detailviewcontroller

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

-(IBAction)denemecik:(id)sender
{
// there is no code here 
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
//NSLog(@"memori warning aldım");
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

here is the .h file :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface detailviewcontroller : UIViewController
{
}
-(IBAction)denemecik:(id)sender;
@end
```

and xib view : there is just one button on the view and i just click it